# The Things Network AWS IoT integration

Tags: mqtt, aws-iot, lora, lorawan

I have followed the tutorial for the AWS integration but cannot get the MQTT messages to display in the AWS IoT Core. I assume bridging is not working since I can get the messages in an external client from the TTN MQTT broker.

I have followed the troubleshooting steps but there is nothing at all in the logs (neither in `app-1.log` nor `app-1.error.log`). I then used ssh to get into the EC2 instance and tried to manually launch the integration with

```sh
/var/app/current/bin/integration-aws run
```

It then crashed with the following error

```
  INFO Initializing AWS IoT client              PolicyName=ttn-integration Region=
 FATAL Failed to get AWS IoT endpoint
```

When setting the `AWS_REGION=eu-west-1` environment variable, I get the following error:

```
  INFO Initializing AWS IoT client              PolicyName=ttn-integration Region=eu-west-1
  INFO Found AWS IoT endpoint                   Endpoint=an3cfmjmy6od4.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  INFO Created certificate                      ID=189326ec8e90c8abd0de2eef1fe6eb4a22c05495c49bcfe291860a6b45243acd
 FATAL Failed to attach policy to certificate   Certificate=189326ec8e90c8abd0de2eef1fe6eb4a22c05495c49bcfe291860a6b45243acd Policy=ttn-integration error=ResourceNotFoundException: Policy not found
        status code: 404, request id: ff8df0e8-56f1-11e9-9368-e107e49fac68
```

I assume there is some sort of configuration file missing but I cannot seem to find anything that mentions such a file.

- Does such a configuration file exist?
- Is there anything else causing this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, trying to launch the integration from an SSH session is a bad idea (it is missing environment variables among other things).

---

With the old version of the integration (before 2.0.11), we somehow needed certificates with an associated policy for the things in the AWS IoT core. This bug is fixed in 2.0.11 (which is the current one at the time of writing this answer).